# Bad behaviour of Barrier in ConstraintLayout in ScrollView

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am using last version of `ConstraintLayout`, 1.1.0-beta4 and I am having issues with Barrier when its `ConstraintLayout` is inside `ScrollView`. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="rs.agilesolutions.anothertesttodelete.MainActivity"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Lorem"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Ipsum"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="bottom"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="txt1,txt2"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="UNDER BARRIER"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtResult"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Barrier's direction is set to `bottom`of two views(`txt1` and `txt2`). It should look like this:

[image: The way it should look like]

, but instead, it looks like this:

[image: The way it looks like]

First, in my **real** app, I have a lot of views and that is the reason `ScrollView` is needed.

Second, by pressing the button I change, for presentation reasons, visibility of `txt` (the one with the **Lorem** text) and thus testing if lower views are behaving correctly.

Third, obviously, as a result, `ConstraintLayout` doesn't take into account that under those views, for which barrier is referenced, it can spread enough to have other content, but instead, it just fills already created space for layout with remaining views from the bottom.

Is this a bug in implementation of `ConstraintLayout`?

Do I have any other choice without the one where I in code change constraints for this kind of situation and regardless of visibility of view, I accordingly set position of the remaining views?

Comment: For me, this looks correctly. Seems to be a bug in beta4. In beta3 all looks fine. Note, that `wrap_content`  on the layout itself can be problematic. It can only work if there is no expanding view (the sample code above should thus work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in version 1.1.0-beta4. I lowered the version to beta3 and everything works as expected.

Comment: FYI 1.1.0 stable does not appear to have the bug anymore

Comment: Well, yes, I know that. The question was asked ten months ago, but thanks, anyway!

Comment: I figured you would know this already, but I was dealing with this issue today so put this here for other readers